# How to disable options in select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to take user's preference with select2. Upon selecting one option the option in other select2 should disable.

Sample:

Preference 1:
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4

Preference 2:
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4

Preference 3:
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4

Preference 4:
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4

If I select option 1 in preference 1 it should disable in preferences 1,2,3,4
and if I select option 2 in preference 2 it should disable in preferences 1,2,3,4
and if I select option 3 in preference 3 it should disable in preferences 1,2,3,4

Again and if I select option 4 in preference 2 it should disable in preferences 1,2,3,4 and option 2 should be available for select in Preferences 3&4.

I have tired various implementations but stuck. Help me out.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 m-t-sm">
    <label> Select Preference 1: </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="pref1" name="pref1" style="width:100%">
    <option value=""> Select Campus Preference 1 </option>
    <option value="N"> N </option>
    <option value="O"> O </option>
    <option value="R"> R </option>
    <option value="S"> S </option>
    </select>
    <label id="pref1-error" class="error" for="pref1"></label>
</div>
.
.
.
```

My current js:

```
$('select[name*="pref"]').change(function(){

    // start by setting everything to enabled
    $('select[name*="pref"] option').prop('disabled',false);

    // loop each select and set the selected value to disabled in all other selects
    $('select[name*="pref"]').each(function(){ 
        var $this = $(this);
        $('select[name*="pref"]').not($this).find('option').each(function(){
           if($(this).attr('value') == $this.val()){            
               $(this).prop('disabled',true);               
           }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can reinitialize select after disabling it use following code

```
$("select").select2("destroy").select2();
```

something like

```
$('select[name*="pref"]').change(function(){

    // start by setting everything to enabled
    $('select[name*="pref"] option').prop('disabled',false);

    // loop each select and set the selected value to disabled in all other selects
    $('select[name*="pref"]').each(function(){ 
        var $this = $(this);
        $('select[name*="pref"]').not($this).find('option').each(function(){
           if($(this).attr('value') == $this.val()){            
               $(this).prop('disabled',true);               
           }
        });
    });
    $('select[name*="pref"]').select2("destroy").select2();
});
```

hope i am getting you right

Comment: am not getting you @Vamshi

Comment: But, once all four options are set, all are disabled and there is no means of resetting options, right? except page refresh. If user wants to change the preferences, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: @Vamshi you could put a button called reset preferences which enables all the options

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks. I did that.                                                                      
                                                                                                             
  var $clear = $("#pref1, #pref2, #pref3, #pref4").select2();

$("#prefclear").on("click", function () { $clear.val(null).trigger("change"); });