# How to disable options in select2 at runtime

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, jquery-select2

In select2 (version 4.0.x) I can't find an easy way of disabling options at runtime.
The best solution so far is calling `destroy` and recreating select2. Even though that works, I'm afraid it will give too much of a performance hit in my production environment with multiple selects and loads of options. And as a bonus I'm getting errors from select2 during the recreate action because of bound events (not in the fiddle).

Check the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/c3ubx018/

To trigger the issue, open all selects one by one.
Then click the toggle button.
Then view the select again.

- first select always keeps the state of the first open.
- second select needs to be opened twice before getting updated.
- third select(the destroy) is the only one that works as desired.

Related question: [How to disable options in select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801724/how-to-disable-options-in-select2)

Besides recreating I've also tried triggering the change event and adding a bogus option to the subtree, all of which works but does not update the existing list items.